# How to call a function multiple times with changing arguments and store them in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, function, statistics

I´m a R-beginner and want to run a simulation, where I call the normal distribution multiple times with different values for sd.

For example, I want to run rnorm with each sd one time, where the sd increases from 1 to M with each  run. And I want to store the results in a list or data frame. I know that what I try to achieve is a pretty basic step, but I failed trying it by myself.

rnorm(n=1, mean=0, sd=1)

rnorm(n=1, mean=0, sd=2)

...
rnorm(n=1, mean=0, sd=M)

I tried to code this with a for loop, but it didnt work.

```
test <- for(i in 1:10){
  test <- rnorm(n=1, mean=0, sd=i)
  return(test)
}
```

If I enter test in the console, I just get NULL as output. Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate 1 values per `i`, you may try

```
res <- c()
for(i in 1:10){
  res <- c(res,rnorm(n=1, mean=0, sd=i))
}
res
[1]  1.3586796 -0.2055755  1.1630148 -0.2152202 -6.8852978 -2.4899674 -2.7600297 -0.4745072  9.9002283  7.6317575
```

The result will be saved in a vector.

If you want to generate several values per `i`, for example, 5 values per `i`.

```
res <- matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 10)
for(i in 1:10){
  res[,i] <- rnorm(n=5, mean=0, sd=i)
}
res
           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]      [,7]         [,8]       [,9]     [,10]
[1,] -0.1645236 -1.4149903  1.194318  7.9215996 12.0080888   1.132754  3.328567  2.331569884  -5.118019  3.329504
[2,] -0.2533617  0.7291639 -1.836079 -1.4688859 -0.1962000 -10.829752 -4.969625 -3.546334986  -1.216608 10.630998
[3,]  0.6969634  1.5370658  1.023359 -4.1765385  3.4486968   8.793329  4.275084  0.008842813  10.602783 -3.041839
[4,]  0.5566632 -0.2246924 -3.388089  2.2788785  0.1400108   0.919520 -6.538683  0.594730593 -13.712101  3.700188
[5,] -0.6887557  1.7622155  4.299071 -0.5402184 -3.7163660  13.035670 -8.775434 -4.716167570   5.345516  2.670988
```

Comment: works like a charm, thanks a lot, @Park :)))

Answer (score 0):

It is good R practice to preallocate arrays. On a sample this small it won't make any functional difference, but your code would be more idiomatic as follows:

```
> k <- 10
> test <- rep(NA, k)
> for(i in 1:k){
+     test[i] <- rnorm(n=1, mean=0, sd=i)
+ }
> test
 [1]  -1.0083914   0.4404118   3.0581583  -8.2564404   3.7986092 -10.9064909  -6.5173390  -3.8936812
 [9]   5.2027044 -11.1803524
```

(In your code above: you don't `return` values from inside `for` loops, and you'd be overwriting your array with the unnecessary assignment in every iteration.)